# mount another drive to the same directory

Tags: partitioning, mount, raid

I recently purchased a server that was advertised as 2TB (2 1TB drives) in size, when I use it it reports only one of the drives, I would like to be able to use both as if one drive.
here is the specs...

```
    sudo lshw -C disk
  *-disk
   description: ATA Disk
   product: TOSHIBA DT01ACA1
   vendor: Toshiba
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sda
   version: MS2O
   serial: 13EJ81XPS
   size: 931GiB (1TB)
   capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
   configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=0005b3dd
  *-disk
   description: ATA Disk
   product: TOSHIBA DT01ACA1
   vendor: Toshiba
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sdb
   version: MS2O
   serial: 13OX3TKPS
   size: 931GiB (1TB)
   capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
   configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=00030e86
```

and

```
    fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00030e86

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        4096    41947135    20971520   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2        41947136  1952468991   955260928   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3      1952468992  1953519615      525312   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005b3dd

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        4096    41947135    20971520   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2        41947136  1952468991   955260928   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3      1952468992  1953519615      525312   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/md2: 978.2 GB, 978187124736 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 238815216 cylinders, total 1910521728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md2 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md1: 21.5 GB, 21474770944 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 5242864 cylinders, total 41942912 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

is it possible to mount both drives to say /Home/ so I would have 2TB of usable space?

Comment: You DO realise that these two disk form a RAID 1 array do you ?

Comment: I am not sure what a RAID 1 array is, all I know is I purchase server with 2TB but am only able to use 1, how can I take full advantage of all 2TB excluding the needed space for OS etc

Comment: No, you are using both without knowing. RAID 1 is a method of harddisk handling where one disk is a perfect copy of the other. A good explanation is done here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/raid-levels-tutorial/ . If you are not familiar with RAID and you don't have any plans on getting familiar with it, then your only option is to wipe both disks and start from scratch. You won't be able to mount two partitions on one mount point.

Comment: so basically I would need to change to a raid 0 system to have full use of both, where raid 1 is a glorified backup system. Is this something I could do myself? if so caould you point me to a resource that would help, or is it something I would need my server company to do for me. I realize I would loose anything on the drives.

Comment: Let your servercompany do it for you if you are not proficient with Linux and want it to work quickly. Otherwise you would be busy for a reasonably frustrating few weeks. But do it yourself if you go for the learning experience, it is not really rocket science. You should start reading  about "mdadm" in that case.

Answer (score 0):

No. with 2TB on /home you have you would use every last bit of possible space. Where would you install your OS on ?

No, you can't mount two devices on one mountpoint

But seriously, two very big partitions together mounted on /home is only possible if those partitions together form a RAID 0 device.

Comment: Be aware thoug that if one drive fails you loose everything because each drive has more or less only half of every file.